# Build pipeline not triggered on PR to master

Tags: azure, azure-devops

On my master branch I have `azure-pipelines.yml` file with:

```
trigger:
  - master
```

I've created a new PR into the master branch:

[image]

But nothing is happening in my build pipeline.

If I complete the PR a the `master` branch is build though.

> Continuous integration (CI) triggers cause a build to run whenever a push is made to the specified branches or a specified tag is pushed.

Am I misreading this? How do I trigger a build on a PR with the Master branch, but without completing the PR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a build to run during a PR, you should set up a branch policy that specifies that build as a validation build.

Comment: Thanks! I had this set up on a "test" branch and it worked great. Merged my stuff with master but now no builds were triggered!

Answer (score 0):

for trigger on PR you need to use PR trigger:

```
pr:
  autoCancel: boolean # indicates whether additional pushes to a PR should cancel in-progress runs for the same PR. Defaults to true
  branches:
    include: [ string ] # branch names which will trigger a build
    exclude: [ string ] # branch names which will not
  paths:
    include: [ string ] # file paths which must match to trigger a build
    exclude: [ string ] # file paths which will not trigger a build
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pr-trigger

Comment: From the documentation: 'A pull request trigger specifies what branches will cause a pull request build to run. If left unspecified, pull requests to every branch will trigger a build'. So if I have no branch specified shouldn't a build be triggered on any pr? No matter the targeted branch? Or wait... Because I specified matter as a trigger it's doing this

Comment: Also from the doc: When you specify a trigger, it replaces the default implicit trigger, and only pushes to branches that are explicitly configured to be included will trigger a pipeline. Includes are processed first, and then excludes are removed from that list. If you specify an exclude but don't specify any includes, nothing will trigger. In my case only a push into master will trigger a build. Not a pr info master

Comment: I'd think that because you specified the trigger implicit triggers are overriden. just a pr trigger